# GO application failed to connect to local PostgreSQL database got error cannot parse

Tags: postgresql, go, cmd, environment-variables, golang-migrate

GO application failed to connect to local PostgreSQL database using environment variables in Windows.

After setting the environment variables using the `windows command prompt` like the following:

```
set DATABASE_HOST=localhost
set DATABASE_USER=postgres
set DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
set DATABASE_NAME=db
set DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

The following command was tried to run the go application:

```
go run main.go
```

I get the following error:

```
←[0m←[31m[error] ←[0mfailed to initialize database, got error cannot parse `host= user= password=xxxxx dbname= port=`: invalid port (strconv.ParseUint: parsing "": invalid syntax)
panic: Failed to connect to database!

goroutine 1 [running]:
        C:/Users/user/go/src/code/db.go:12 +0xb4
```

This is the code for the db.go

```
import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func ConnectDatabase(dsn string) *gorm.DB {
    database, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))

    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect to database!")
    }

    return database
}
```

But when `echo` command was tried it does return the correct value in the command prompt. Example `echo %DATABASE_PORT%` command returns `5432`.

Note: main.go has the database migration related to code to initialize the database tables and schemas and works fine in Linux and Mac OS.

Comment: What is the value of `dsn`? It should look something like `host=localhost user=postgres password=password dbname=db port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai`. Maybe change panic to  `panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to connect to database - %s", dsn))` (but note that this may dump a password to logs so revert when issue fixed).

Comment: What is reading in the environment variable for `DATABASE_PORT`?

Comment: The value of dsn is weirdly ` host= user= password= dbname= port=` so panic returns `panic: Failed to connect to database - host= user= password= dbname= port=` @Brits. The value of `DATABASE_PORT` is set to 5432 @mikequentel

Comment: The issue is not in the code you have shown us. You need to look at how `dsn` is being set (somewhere you should be accessing the environmental variables). Also please note that setting variables in one terminal window will have no impact on others...

Comment: You seem to think that if set, these environment variables will be automatically consumed by gorm, but I see no documentation that supports that belief.  I think you have to do that yourself